# In what scenario is this Opinion-Based?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

[What format are most Hearthstone tournaments using?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184116/what-format-are-most-hearthstone-tournaments-using)

I edited my question to make it very clearly not opinion based and it went from being on-hold to closed. There is absolutely nothing opinion based about asking what the most common tournament formats are, so I don't know why this wasn't reopened.

In fact here's a somewhat similar question about Team Fortress 2: [What type of competitive gaming is available to the public TF2 Community?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152947/what-type-of-competitive-gaming-is-available-to-the-public-tf2-community) --- if anything my question is LESS opinion-based than this one.

Answer (score 3):

"Closed" is just the next stage after "On Hold", which just means a certain amount of time has passed without the question being reopened. If it still remained closed after that, it would eventually be deleted. These are all automatic processes.

The question did have a number of reopen votes. I didn't see anything inherently wrong with it in its current state, so I reopened it for you.